# Select the first row since a column was changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For SQL Server I have a table called hcp_funding_packages with

```
client_sysid (int)
package_level (int)
created_at (datetime)
```

For each client_sysid, I need the entry for the latest package_level change.

So for example if I have the following

| client_sysid | package_level | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-01-02 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-01-03 |
| **1** | **1** | **2021-01-04** |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-05 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-06 |

then I need the bold row on the 4th

Comment: Sorry Dale I didn't even know where to begin, I hadn't tried anything because I knew it wasn't a simple matter of grouping by and selecting whichever was first. I knew I'd need some table expression or SOMETHING, but not how to explain what I needed. Charlieface knew exactly and has answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `LEAD` and `ROW_NUMBER` window functions for this

```sql
WITH Changed AS (
    SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN package_level <> LEAD(package_level, 1, -999) OVER (PARTITION BY client_sysid ORDER BY date DESC)
           THEN 1 END AS IsDifferent
    FROM hcp_funding_packages fp
),
Numbered AS (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client_sysid ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
    FROM Changed fp
    WHERE IsDifferent = 1
)
SELECT
  client_sysid,
  package_level,
  date
FROM Numbered fp
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eaf8e5ecff90ed3f98ef83ae4f835dfe)

Make sure you have an index on `(client_sysid, date DESC)` if you want this to be performant.

Comment: Thanks that works and was ridiculously fast. Is it possible to learn this power?

Comment: Google "SQL window functions" that should get you started